# How to convert csv file in S3 bucket to RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm pretty new with this topic so any help will be much appreciated.

I trying to read a csv file which is stored in a S3 bucket and convert its data to an RDD to work directly with it without the need to create a file locally.

So far I've been able to load the file using AmazonS3ClientBuilder, but the only thing I've got is to have the file content in a S3ObjectInputStream and I'm not able to work with its content.

```
val bucketName = "bucket-name"

val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
   "acessKey",
   "secretKey"
);

val s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
    .build();

val s3object = s3client.getObject(bucketName, "file-name.csv")
val inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent()
....
```

I have also tried to use a BufferedSource to work with it but once done, I don't know how to convert it to a dataframe or RDD to work with it.

```
val myData = Source.fromInputStream(inputStream)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with S3A file system provided in Hadoop-AWS module:

1. Add this dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws
2. Either define `<property><name>fs.s3.impl</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value></property>` in core-site.xml or add `.config("fs.s3.impl", classOf[S3AFileSystem].getName)` to `SparkSession` builder
3. Access S3 using `spark.read.csv("s3://bucket/key")`. If you want the RDD that was asked `spark.read.csv("s3://bucket/key").rdd`

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your help @ollik1, 

I kind of tried this solution before, but came with the following error:

`Error:(17, 37) Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.StreamCapabilities not found - continuing with a stub.
      .config("fs.s3.impl", classOf[S3AFileSystem].getName)`

I've already the corresponding library dependency included in the sbt file: 
**_libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.2.0"_**

and I have no idea of how to avoid this error.

Comment: It's most likely due to incompatible classes. Take a look of the latest spark https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/2.4.2 , it depends on hadoop `2.6.5` so might be easiest to go with `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.6.5"`. It is also possible to make spark to work with newer hadoop versions, I have used `3.0.0` with S3 support but it requires disabling hive support and some manual dependency tweaks.

Comment: Sorry to reply so late @ollik1 , I wasn't able to solve the issue regarding StreamCapabilities so I ended up loading the S3 file taking a look at https://gist.github.com/snowindy/d438cb5256f9331f5eec

But as said, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I was able to get the results I was searching for taking a look at https://gist.github.com/snowindy/d438cb5256f9331f5eec